# Magento admin menu block is not showing in configuration tab?

Tags: php, xml, magento, magento-1.7

I am just a newbie to the [magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/) extensions. I want to create a new module named as `storeinfo` in `magento version 1.7.0.2` . For that I have my folder structure for `app/local` is like this

```
magento directory
  app
    code
      community
      core
      local---
            |--- New(foldername)--
                  |---Storeinfo(foldername)--
                        |-Block
                          controllers
                          etc
                          Helper
                          sql
```

code for `New_Storeinfo.xml` which is inside `magentodirectory/app/etc` is something like this

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <New_Storeinfo>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
    </New_Storeinfo>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Now inside the directory `magentodirectory/app/code/local/New/Storeinfo/etc/config.xml` is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <New_Storeinfo>
      <version>0.1.1</version>
    </New_Storeinfo>
  </modules>

  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <storeinfo>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
          <module>New_Storeinfo</module>
          <frontName>storeinfo</frontName>
        </args>
      </storeinfo>
    </routers>
    <layout>
      <updates>
        <storeinfo>
          <file>newstoreinfo.xml</file>
        </storeinfo>
      </updates>
    </layout>
  </frontend>

  <adminhtml>
    <acl>
      <resources>
        <all>
          <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
          <children>
            <system>
              <children>
                <config>
                  <children>
                    <storeinfo>
                      <title>Store Map</title>
                    </storeinfo>
                  </children>
                </config>
              </children>
            </system>
          </children>
        </admin>
      </resources>
    </acl>
  </adminhtml>

  <global>
        <models>
            <storeinfo>
                <class>New_Storeinfo_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>storeinfo_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </storeinfo>
        </models>
    <resources>
            <storeinfo_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>New_Storeinfo</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </storeinfo_setup>
            <storeinfo_write>
                <connection>
                  <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </storeinfo_write>
            <storeinfo_read>
               <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
              </connection>
            </storeinfo_read>
        </resources>
    <blocks>
            <storeinfo><class>New_Storeinfo_Block</class></storeinfo>
        </blocks>
    <helpers>
            <storeinfo>
                <class>New_Storeinfo_Helper</class>
            </storeinfo>
        </helpers>
    </global>
  <default>
        <storeinfo>
      <address>
        <enabled>1</enabled>
        <title>Our Store Address</title>
        <address>Replace this with Your Address with or without HTML code here....</address>
      </address>
      <storeinfo>
        <enabled>1</enabled>
        <title>Our Location Map</title>
        <map_location>Paste Map HTML code here...</map_location>
      </storeinfo>
    </storeinfo>
    </default>
</config>
```

Now for the directory  `magentodirectory/app/code/local/New/Storeinfo/etc/system.xml` my code is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <storeinfo translate="label" module="storeinfo">
            <label>Store Map &amp; Address</label>
            <sort_order>132</sort_order>
        </storeinfo>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <storeinfo translate="label" module="storeinfo">
            <label>Map &amp; Address Info.</label>
            <tab>storeinfo</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <storeinfo translate="label">
                    <label>Settings</label>
                    <comment><![CDATA[
                        <p>
                            <div>Add Store info:</div>
                        </p>
                    ]]></comment>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <enabled translate="label">
                            <label>Enabled</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </enabled>
                        <title translate="label">
                            <label>Title</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </title>
                        <map_location translate="label">
                            <label>Location Map HTML code</label>
                            <frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <comment><![CDATA[Collect you store map html code from any of the maps code provides like <strong>Google, Yahoo..</strong>]]></comment>
                        </map_location>
                    </fields>
                </storeinfo>
                <address translate="label">
                    <label>Address</label>
                    <comment><![CDATA[
                        <p>
                            <div>Add Store Address to your Magento Store:</div>
                        </p>
                    ]]></comment>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <enabled translate="label">
                            <label>Enabled</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </enabled>
                        <title translate="label">
                            <label>Title</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </title>
                        <address translate="label">
                            <label>Address</label>
                            <frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <comment>Put you store address with or without HTML code</comment>
                        </address>
                    </fields>
                </address>
            </groups>
        </storeinfo>
    </sections>
</config>
```

But after all the codes the menu for Storeinfo is not showing in magento's admin configuration tab. So can someone kindly tell me what is the issue here?Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks...

Comment: you go to system-->configuration-->Advanced--> enable Disable Modules Output--> check if you modules created or not.

Comment: @VIVEK-MDU yes the module is showing in advanced but it is not showing in configuration tab.I have tried many times to make it on and ff from advanced tab.. but nothing is happening...

Comment: read this article http://www.webspeaks.in/2010/08/create-your-first-adminbackend-module.html

Comment: and also read this http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/create-configuration-for-your-magento-extension/

Comment: Do you have a helper called Data.php in you helper folder? Have you refreshed your cache?

Comment: yes.. in that I have my code is like this
`class New_Storeinfo_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract`

Comment: Zip the folder you have and upload it somewhere so we can look at it.

Comment: can you give me your mail id so that I can send you the module...

Answer (score 1):

Try this way. Its used to create a menu tab for magento admin.

Create your folder structure for your needs.

then **app/code/local/company_name/module_name/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <JR_CreateAdminController>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </JR_CreateAdminController>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <jr_createadmincontroller>
                <!-- Helper definition needed by Magento -->
                <class>Mage_Core_Helper</class>
            </jr_createadmincontroller>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <foo_bar before="Mage_Adminhtml">JR_CreateAdminController_Adminhtml</foo_bar>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

then you create admin panel menu using this way **app/code/community/company_name/module_name/etc/adminhtml.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <mycustomtab module="jr_createadmincontroller" translate="title">
            <title>My Custom Tab</title>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            <children>
                <index module="jr_createadmincontroller" translate="title">
                    <title>Index Action</title>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/custom</action>
                </index>
                <list module="jr_createadmincontroller" translate="title">
                    <title>List Action</title>
                    <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/custom/list</action>
                </list>
            </children>
        </mycustomtab>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <custom translate="title" module="jr_createadmincontroller">
                        <title>My Controller</title>
                        <sort_order>-100</sort_order>
                        <children>
                            <index translate="title">
                                <title>Index Action</title>
                                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            </index>
                            <list translate="title">
                                <title>List Action</title>
                                <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                            </list>
                        </children>
                    </custom>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

you can create own controller for your module
**app/code/community/company_name/module_name/controllers/Adminhtml/CustomController.php**

```
<?php

class JR_CreateAdminController_Adminhtml_CustomController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout()
            ->_setActiveMenu('mycustomtab')
            ->_title($this->__('Index Action'));

        // my stuff

        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function listAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout()
            ->_setActiveMenu('mycustomtab')
            ->_title($this->__('List Action'));

        // my stuff

        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

and you want to create configuration tab :
create system.xml and use this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <inchoo translate="label" module="mymodule">
            <label>Inchoo Extensions</label>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        </inchoo>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <inchoo translate="label" module="mymodule">
            <label>Extension Options</label>
            <tab>inchoo</tab>
            <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <inchoo_group translate="label" module="mymodule">
                    <label>My Extension Options</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <inchoo_input translate="label">
                            <label>My Input Field: </label>
                            <comment>My Comment</comment>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </inchoo_input>
                        <inchoo_select translate="label">
                            <label>My Dropdown: </label>
                            <comment>Source model provider Magento's default Yes/No values</comment>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>90</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                        </inchoo_select>
                    </fields>
                </inchoo_group>
            </groups>
        </inchoo>
    </sections>
</config>
```

I'm sure this would work for you.

Answer (score 1):

The question was answered on [magento.stackexchange.com](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/6639/146) with additional details.
The problem is in the declaration xml file. The tag `<codepool>` should be `<codePool>` - uppercase `P`.

Comment: I have changed <codepool> to <codePool> with uppercase p but still it is showing the same problem...check my updated question...

Comment: Did you clear the cache?. I've copied your code on my local Magento instance, and after changing to `<codePool>` everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

remove the below code from config.xml

```
<adminhtml>
    <acl>
      <resources>
        <all>
          <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
          <children>
            <system>
              <children>
                <config>
                  <children>
                    <storeinfo>
                      <title>Store Map</title>
                    </storeinfo>
                  </children>
                </config>
              </children>
            </system>
          </children>
        </admin>
      </resources>
    </acl>
  </adminhtml>
```

and create an adminhtml.xml file in etc folder with below content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <acl>
      <resources>
        <all>
          <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
          <children>
            <system>
              <children>
                <config>
                  <children>
                    <storeinfo>
                      <title>Store Map</title>
                    </storeinfo>
                  </children>
                </config>
              </children>
            </system>
          </children>
        </admin>
      </resources>
    </acl>
  </config>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a generator to build most of the basic stuff like that to avoid spelling errors etc.

http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator

Answer (score 1):

Unless it was a typo, you mention your New_Storeinfo.xml is located in:

```
magentodirectory/app/etc
```

This should actually be located in this folder:

```
magentodirectory/app/etc/modules
```

Refresh cache, and now your module should show up under System -> Configuration -> Advanced

Answer (score 0):

You didn't have this problem but for posterity's sake I've noticed that if you have any comments in your `/app/etc/modules/New_Storeinfo.xml` file, the module won't show up in System > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced :: Disable Modules Output